# Prove that c uses row-major order for arranging two-dimensional arrays

Tags: c

I'm trying to prove that c uses row-major order as memory structure so I'm measuring the time to create a row-major array vs. column-major array (multiplication * 2).

The problem is that something isn't quite right with the algorithm of the loops subrow(array) and subcol(array). The row-major order should produce less misses in the cache and thus be faster than column major but I constantly get the opposite. If you run the code you'll get something like this:

Row-major took 6511 miliseconds.
Column-major took 5690 miliseconds.

Please help me sort out the algorithm.

Edit:
It was pointed out that I am not actually accessing the array so I am not testing access speed. I added sum += array[i][j]; to the subcol and subrow loop, but I am still getting the same consistent result that row-major order is performing slower whereas the opposite should be true. Perhaps something is wrong with the way I am setting i and j in the loops.
Output:
subrow sum = 784293664
Row-major took 6737 miliseconds.
subcol sum = 784293664
Column-major took 6594 miliseconds.

Updated Code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <sys/time.h>

  #define ROW 1000
  #define COL 1000

  void subrow(int array[ROW][COL]);
  void subcol(int array[ROW][COL]);

  int main()
  {

      int array[ROW][COL];

      int i, j;

      for(i=0;i<ROW;i++)        // sets the array to each element to x*y then multiplies by 2
      {
          for (j=0; j<COL; j++)
              {
              array[i][j]=i*j;
              array[i][j]=array[i][j]*2;
              }
      }

      subrow(array);        //calls the max row function
      subcol(array);        //calls the max col function

      return 0;

  }

  void subrow(int array[ROW][COL])
  {
      int i,j;

      struct timeval stop, start;
      gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
  int sum = 0;

      for (i=0;i<ROW;i++)
      {
              for (j=0; j<COL; j++)
         {
    sum += array[i][j];
         }
      }

      printf("subrow sum = %d\n", sum);
      gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
      printf("Row-major took %lu miliseconds.\n", (stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec));

      return;
  }

  void subcol(int array[ROW][COL])
  {
      int i,j;

      struct timeval stop, start;    //
      gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

  int sum = 0;

      for (i=0; i<COL;i++)
      {
              for (j=0; j<ROW; j++)
              {
              sum += array[i][j];
              }
      }
      printf("subcol sum = %d\n", sum);
      gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
      printf("Column-major took %lu miliseconds.\n", (stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec));

      return;
  }
```

Comment: plz show all the code... or are the loops really empty? ;)

Comment: more simply, compare `&a[0][1] - &a[0][0]` to `&a[1][0] - &a[0][0]`

Comment: Can you give me an example how I could compare these?

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i=0;i<ROW;i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<COL; j++)
    {
    }
}
```

You're not actually accessing the arrays in these loops. You're just iterating with a couple of int variables. You need to actually read from or write to `array[i][j]` if you want to test access speed.

For instance:

```
int sum = 0;

for (i=0;i<ROW;i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<COL; j++)
    {
        sum += array[i][j];
    }
}

// Do something with `sum` so the compiler doesn't optimize it, and the loops above,
// away.
printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand -- how can I actually read from array[i][j] with these loops? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I added your suggestion to the code but I'm still getting a faster result for column-major whereas the opposite should be true. I'm starting to think I defined the loops wrong (j and i)? :/